# Excel formulae rewrite using pow()

Tags: php, pow

I am getting myself in a bit of a muddle trying to re-write the following excel formulae in php using pow() to substitute ^:

```
$I5*(1+$C25)^(($C9-$E5))*(1-$C16)^($C10-$F5)*(1+$C12)^(($C20-$C21)/365.25)
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

//////////////////////

Answer

Thanks Mark, your answer helped come to the solution:

$I5*pow((1+$C25),(($C9-$E5)))*pow((1-$C16),($C10-$F5))*pow((1+$C12),(($C20-$C21)/365.25));

Comment: We're not a code translation service. YOU show what you've tried so far, and we'll try help it. There are far too many people who simply expect us to do their job for them, claim they've tried something, haven't actually done anything, and yet get mad when we won't "help" them.

Comment: Apologies. I had researched and tried a lot before hand (hence knowing pow was to be used). In future I will post my working along with any questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$I5*pow((1+$C25),(($C9-$E5)))*pow((1-$C16),($C10-$F5))*pow((1+$C12),(($C20-$C21)/365.25));
```